# JQuery AJAX cross-site request under Laravel CSRF protection

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, csrf

I'm building a CMS-like web application using Laravel(back-end) and ReactJS with JQuery(front-end).

I decide to put the existing Web API into a separate domain(api.test.com), and my user interface is on the different domain(test.com).

On **test.com**, I launch an ajax request to **api.test.com** to modify some resource on the server:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "api.test.com",
    method: 'POST',
    data: {...}
    success: function (no) {
    // ...
    }
  });
```

And of course it's illegal due to security problem. However, I can configure my web server:

For Nginx:

```
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://test.com;
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods GET,POST,PUT,DELETE;
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers X-Requested-With,X-CSRF-TOKEN,X-XSRF-TOKEN;
```

The **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** problem is solved perfectly but another problem occurs due to **Laravel's CSRF** protection...

Laravel requires a CSRF token included in the request(POST,PUT...which will modify the resource) by default.

In my case, I must generate **csrf_token** on **api.test.com** rather than **test.com** because different domain do not share the token.

I followed the User Guide of Laravel and added these code to my front-end:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "api.test.com/token", // simply return csrf_token();
    method: "GET",
    success: function (token) {
      // Now I get the token
      _token = token;
    }.bind(this)
  });
```

and modify the previous request implementation:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "api.test.com",
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      "X-CSRF-TOKEN": _token // Here I passed the token
    },
    data: {...}
    success: function (no) {
    // ...
    }
  });
```

But Laravel responses a status code of 500. Then I checked the **VerifyCsrfToken.php**:

```
protected function tokensMatch($request)
{
    $token = $request->input('_token') ?: $request->header('X-CSRF-TOKEN');
    if (!$token && $header = $request->header('X-XSRF-TOKEN')) {
        $token = $this->encrypter->decrypt($header);
    }
    // Log::info($request->session()->token() . " == $token");
    return Str::equals($request->session()->token(), $token);
}
```

The **$token** which I '**POST**' to is different from what it was (**$request->session()->token()**).

I found that the validation tokens on server are different when calling $.ajax.

I try to put the two requests in the same session(by changing the cookie), but it's impossible.

I spent a lot of time to solve this problem but didn't work it out.

Have any idea or solution?

Thanks,
Micooz

Comment: I'd add code to VerifyCsrfToken that exempts your API routes from the need for a CSRF token.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for answering my question. I've considered **disabling** the CSRF protection to some URIs but I don't want to take these risk.

The key point of my question is that the $.ajax forgets carrying cookies before request, and resulting token validation failed.

Now I setup the JQuery Ajax, let it carry cookies before make a request.

```
  $.ajaxSetup({
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }
  });
```

and Nginx conf:

```
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true;
```

BTW, it's not necessary to include the token in the data:{}(**Form**).

All the problems are settled and it works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel expects the token as a data variable, included on your fields, the name of the var needs to be `_token` try to change it.

Another solution is including the token in your data not in the headers.

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "api.test.com",
    method: 'POST',
    data: { _token : _token }
    success: function (no) {
    // ...
    }
  });
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried this solution but it didn't work. I guess I got a wrong token from api.test.com because of the two different sessions made by $.ajax.

Answer (score -1):

You can follow this url

```
http://laravel.io/forum/11-14-2014-disabling-the-csrf-middleware-in-laravel-5
```

In this link, you need to wrap up `VerifyCsrfToken` class with new one class where you specify actions on which you want not use csrf_token